# How to prove this identity between two q-series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

How to prove the following identity?
\begin{align}
 (1 - q^2) \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}q^n\sum_{\substack{\ell = - n/2 \\ \ell \ne 0 }}^{+n/2} \frac{b^{2\ell}}{q^\ell - q^{-\ell}}
 = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}q^n \frac{b^n - b^{-n}}{q^{n/2} - q^{-n/2}} \ .
\end{align}

References on identities of this type would be great.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is actually fairly simple. Basically there are two ingredients,
\begin{align}
 & \ \frac{1}{1 - q^2}\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty}a_n q^n
 = \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \sum_{\ell = 0}^{+\infty} a_n q^{2\ell + n}
 = \sum_{N = 1}^{+\infty} \sum_{\ell = 0}^{\lfloor\frac{N-1}{2} \rfloor} a_{N - 2\ell} q^N \\
 = & \ \sum_{N = 1}^{+\infty}q^N \sum_{\ell = \frac{N}{2} - \lfloor \frac{N-1}{2} \rfloor}^{\frac{N}{2}}a_{2\ell} \ ,
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
 & \ \sum_{\substack{m = - n/2 \\ m \ne 0}}^{+n/2} \frac{b^{2m}}{q^m - q^{-m}} = \sum_{\ell = \frac{n}{2} - \lfloor \frac{n - 1}{2} \rfloor}^{\frac{n}{2}} \frac{b^{2\ell} - b^{-2\ell}}{q^\ell - q^{-\ell}} \  .
\end{align}

Combine the two, the identity can be proven.